# RX.JS Redux Observable Multiple Get requests at same time

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I am trying to set up an observable that currently receives an array of location IDs and then makes a get request for all of these at once and waits for the response for them all. Here is a sample:

```
const fetchPhotosEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(LOCATIONS_RECEIVED)
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .mergeMap((data) =>  {
        let promiseArray = data.map(location => Observable.fromPromise(axios.get(photosUrl(location.id))))
        return Observable.forkJoin(
           promiseArray
        )
    })
    .map(responses => responses.map((response) => response.data.location))
```

Where data looks like:

```
[
    {
        id: "aoeuaeu",
        name: "Test"
    },
  ...
]
```

The issue I have right now is I get a 404 on one of the requests and it's messing everything up. I am probably doing something wrong as I am just learning RX. Any help would be great!

Comment: Hey there. Is the issue that you want to handle cases where one or more of the requests fails in some way? What would you like to happen? Do you really need to wait for all the requests to finish? It also doesn’t look like you’re epic is emitting an action, instead emitting the data itself—is that an omission in the question or an issue?

Comment: @jayphelps, ya I didn't post the entire epic. If one of them fails I can just ignore it. I ideally want to wait for all to return because I will get a list of photos from each one and then want to sort them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try adding a catch to each call and returning a new observable with the error message, which should stop the forkJoin failing if one request fails. You can then either filter out the failures, or add logic to handle them in your final .map. eg.

```
const fetchPhotosEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(LOCATIONS_RECEIVED)
    .map(action => action.payload)
    .mergeMap((data) => {
        let promiseArray = data.map(location => {
            return Observable.fromPromise(axios.get(photosUrl(location.id)))
                .catch(error => Observable.of({error}))
      })
      return Observable.forkJoin(
          promiseArray
      )
  })
 .filter(response => !Boolean(response.error))
 .map(responses => responses.map((response) => response.data.location))
```

Comment: Gorgeous! Thanks :)